# Changing my state without calling the api using redux saga?

Tags: react-redux, redux-saga

I have something to ask, I see that there is always a call to an api in the documentation, but I don't need any API when changing a variable from french to english or the opposite, so how can I do it ?

Here is what I have tried so far :

```
<Button
   content={intl("FRENCH")}
   type="link"
   color="link"
   size="medium"
   entire={false}
   onClick={() =>
     this.props.changeLanguage({ language: "ENGLISH_LANGUAGE" })
   }
   >
</Button>
```

My action changeLanguage is working just fine, I tested it with console log and here is the action :

```
export const changeLanguage = ({ language }) => {
  console.log(language);
  return {
    type: language
  };
};
```

And here is my saga :

```
import { changeLanguage } from "../../Actions/Language/language";
import { takeEvery, put, call, fork } from "redux-saga/effects";

function* changeCurrentLanguage({ type }) {
  yield put({ type: "ENGLISH_LANGUAGE_CHANGE" });
}

function* watchChangeLanguage() {
  yield takeEvery("ENGLISH_LANGUAGE", changeCurrentLanguage);
}

const languageSaga = [fork(watchChangeLanguage)];

export default languageSaga;
```

Here is the root saga :

```
import { all } from "redux-saga/effects";
import connectionSaga from "./Authentification/connection";
import languageSaga from "./Language/language";

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([...connectionSaga, ...languageSaga]);
}
```

My simple reducer :

```
const initialState = {
  language: "en"
};

export default function languageReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ENGLISH_LANGUAGE_CHANGE":
      console.log("ENGLISH");
      return { ...state, language: "en" };
    case "FRENCH_LANGUAGE":
      return { ...state, language: "fr" };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I am using the put method to dispatch the action, but the action with ENGLISH_LANGUAGE_CHANGE is not triggered, Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you don't need to call the API, you don't need a saga.  Just use a regular action/reducer.

Comment: I see, thanks for that